# Is it possible to upload a local snapshot to Amazon Elasticsearch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-elasticsearch

First time working with Elasticsearch. I was wondering how to migrate my local data (a local instalation in my computer of ES) into Amazon ES, be it with a snapshot, which I found was one way to do it or by other means. I made a snapshot, which is 174mb big, the index I was working on has about 120k entries. I'm working with version 5.6.2.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to upload it to s3 and restore it from there , try from [this blog](https://medium.com/@federicopanini/elasticsearch-backup-snapshot-and-restore-on-aws-s3-f1fc32fbca7f)

Hope it helps